# NSDate. Grabbing all dates before today

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, nsdate

I am trying to use this [calendar component](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar) and my task is to make disabled visually and technically all dates before today's date. User can switch between months also and I need to have all dates before today disabled, even if it will be date of a few years ago. `disabledDateTextColor` and `disabledDateBackgroundColor` types are also defined for this calendar but no dates calculation methods. I am reading `NSDate` documentation and looks like I can't do that directly, using system method (i mean method what return array of dates before or after date or something similar). Looks like adding all existing days before today to `NSArray` and marking them as disabled before drawing calendar is an obvious overkill, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In My previous application i used this method

```
switch ([dateOne compare:dateTwo]) {
case NSOrderedAscending:
    // dateOne is earlier in time than dateTwo
    break;
case NSOrderedSame:
    // The dates are the same
    break;
case NSOrderedDescending:
    // dateOne is later in time than dateTwo
    break;
}
```

both date formatter  should be similar 
read Instance Methods in below link for more info

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:

Comment: Thanks for your attention, Prakash! Main question is: Do I need to use array, fill it with all dates of month and mark all of them as I need iterating through array, or does exist a more generic decision to solve this?

Comment: array and for loop is the way to go :] in that switch you put value of array objectAtIndex and today date and thats it